# Oracle SQL comparison operator(ALL) behavior

Tags: sql

I'm new to oracle sql & trying to query a database with the following select statement

```
select first_name || last_name "Name", 
       department_id 
from employees 
where department_id >= all (80,90,100);"
```

The result I was expecting was all 80s, 90s, 100s and above but I get 100s and above. Why can't I see 80s and 90s? Here's a screenshot.

```
SQL> select first_name|| ' ' || last_name "Name", department_id
  2  from employees where department_id >= all (80, 90, 100);

Name                                           DEPARTMENT_ID
---------------------------------------------- -------------
Nancy Greenberg                                          100
Daniel Faviet                                            100
John Chen                                                100
Ismael Sciarra                                           100
Jose Manuel Urman                                        100
Luis Popp                                                100
Shelley Higgins                                          110
William Gietz                                            110
```

8 rows selected.

```
SQL> select distinct department_id from employees;

DEPARTMENT_ID
-------------
      100
       30

       90
       20
       70
      110
       50
       80
       40
       60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `>= ALL (...)`, the check is that your value is greater than or equal to the largest value in the list. Your list, in this case, is (80,90,100), so only those values which are greater than or equal to 100 are part of the result set.

Check this link for a more thorough understanding of `ALL`:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php

If you wanted to get all records where the department is either 80,90 or 100 i.e. exact match with any of the 3 values, you should use the `IN` keyword like so:

```
select first_name|| ' ' || last_name "Name", department_id 
from employees 
where department_id in (80, 90, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the difference between ALL comparator.

- "x = ALL (...)": The value must match all the values in the list to evaluate to TRUE.
- "x != ALL (...)": The value must not match any values in the list to evaluate to TRUE.
- "x > ALL (...)": The value must be greater than the biggest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE.
- "x < ALL (...)": The value must be smaller than the smallest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE.
- **"x >= ALL (...)": The value must be greater than or equal to the biggest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE.**
- "x <= ALL (...)": The value must be smaller than or equal to the smallest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE.

Taken from [Oracle-Base.com](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php)

Comment: This looks familiar. Would be good if you could cite the source.

Comment: this is worth memorizing specially when i'm taking oracle sql basic exam.

Comment: Here's a link but with some googling you might be able to find a pdf for free... http://www.amazon.com/OCA-Administrator-Certified-Associate-Exams1Z0-051/dp/0470395125/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1406689651&sr=1-2-fkmr0&keywords=biju+k.+thomas+oca